# Is there any way to set file attributes in node js

Tags: node.js, file-attributes

Not sure about unix, but in windows you can add attributes to files, like a location on a photo file or a duration on a video file.

Is there a way to do this in node js. Would be very handy with my currently project. It would save me having to create separate attribute data files.

Comment: You're confusing file attributes, which are part of the the filesystem structure with metadata which may or may be present in part of the file format or some types of files.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [WinAttr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winattr) package to do that.

Comment: I guess that would work, but windows only it seems. Pretty sure a lot of cloud systems are on some kind of unix these days. Thanks for the suggestion through.

Answer (score 2):

See this module:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/winattr

But it's for attributes like archive, hidden, readonly, system.

I don't think you can add an attribute of of duration to the video file - the duration is written in the container/codec of the video itself. The location for images is in the EXIF data - which can be manipulated with other modules on npm - see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=EXIF

For the location on a photo file or a duration on a video file you need to use whatever information is appropriate for that given image or video format.

Comment: I guess that would work, but windows only it seems. Pretty sure a lot of cloud systems are on some kind of unix these days. Thanks for the suggestion through. Location and duration were just examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a SHELL command:

```js
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

// Remove Hidden and system attributes:
execSync("attrib -h -s " + yourFolder);

// Add Hidden attribute:
execSync("attrib +h " + yourFolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fs-xattr` works like a charm for linux:

Check it out here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-xattr